# Flask: how to change the value passed in render_template

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bokeh

I'm now trying to use flask to display some bokeh plots as well as pictures. The bokeh part is well, I can change the source and thus update the plot using ajax. But when I try to update the src of image I met some problem.

First let me show part of my code, I just pass a variable called "fname" to html in render_template() and give it to img tag:

```py
    return render_template('index.html',
                           script=script,
                           div=div,
                           fname=fname,
                           js_resources=INLINE.render_js(),
                           css_resources=INLINE.render_css())
```

and in html like this:

```
<img id="frame" src= {{ url_for('static', filename=fname ) | safe}} />
```

The image showed well but then I want to change the fname by some click, in customJS I write:

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(imgDir=img_dir, fname=fname), code="""
var x = Math.floor(cb_obj.x);
var dir = imgDir;
var fname = fname;
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/img',
        data: {"idx": x},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            fname = response['fname'];
            alert(fname);
            fname.change.emit();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occured!");
        }
    });
""")
```

I use alert to test fname and it's correct, but it seems that the 'fname' is not that fname I passed in render_template(), so actually the image path didn't change.

Of course there's another solution, just find img and change its src totally, but in that case I have to give the absolute path rather than the relative path.

**Here's my question: **How can I change 'fname' through ajax request rather than just change the whole src path, cuz I want to use 'static' path I defined.

Thanks!